# Locking certain applications

Tags: restricted-access, parental-controls

In my family, I'm the computer guy (17yo btw).
My brother got a laptop for christmas, and now, not even a month later, he managed to already mess it up (will freeze after a few mins of use and frequently get BSODs). So I dug up his old laptop (a Fujitsu from 2009) and installed Lubuntu on it.

It runs pretty well and can even play back 720p Youtube, so this is a winner. However, I do want to restrict his access to certain applications so that he doesn't accidentally mess up another system. How can I do that?

And I think I would almost prefer a whitelist system over a blacklist system, as he basically only needs LibreOffice and Firefox for school at home.

Comment: Well, do not give him root and he won't be able to install anything :)

Comment: You haven't provided release details; ie. if you're talking about legacy Lubuntu (using LXDE) or modern Lubuntu using LXQt. Many details may not change, but links with detail (such as the Lubuntu manual) differ.

Comment: Rinzwind's answer is good, but I would also recommend setting a GRUB password. Otherwise if he starts digging around for ways to bypass your security, he may learn about recovery mode. Also keep live USBs away from him. Also be prepared for him to shred his user configuration if he's one to dig around like I was as a child. You may need to make new user accounts for him every so often, and migrate his files from the old one to the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic method is to create a normal account and to make yourself admin on that system. Create a good password for the admin and he will not be able to install, remove software and not be able to alter any files outside his own home.

All other privileges can be allowed using `sudo visudo`. There you can grant permissions to execute any command that would require admn rights.